# Using roof of a graph as x-axis for another

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I've plotted a graph using pcolor which gives me the following graph-
[image: basic]

My aim is to use the roof of the graph (by roof) I mean the highest axis (in this case, the line which is defined by y=57) as the base for a further graph.

I was able to use `hold on` to generate the following-
[image: wrong]

Code for this (removed some parts that defined the axis labels etc for brevity)-

```
load sparsemap ;
load d ;
residues = 57 ;

z = zeros(residues,residues); % define the matrix
index = find(sparsemap(:,3) ~= 0) ;
values = length(index);

hold on
%Plots the map you see in the first photo-
for k = 1:values
z(sparsemap(index(k),1),sparsemap(index(k),2)) = sparsemap(index(k),3);
z(sparsemap(index(k),2),sparsemap(index(k),1)) = sparsemap(index(k),3);
end

%Plots the line plot at the bottom of the graph.

A = d(:,1);
B = d(:,2) ;
plot(A, B) ;


pcolor(1:residues,1:residues,z);
works = load('colormap_works');
colormap(works);
colorbar;
```

As you can see, the line plot is using the same x axis as the first graph.

I am trying to get the line plot to come **on top** of the figure. I imagine a final figure like so-
[image: desired]

Any ideas as to how I can use the top part of the first graph?

Comment: Set all `y` values of your desired line to `y+57`, and they'll be centred around there instead of around `0`.

Comment: @Adriaan, thanks. But if possible I would like to have a separate y axis that starts from 0 for the line plot (rather than starting from 57). As you can see, the line plot has y values of 0-3. I would like the y axis to reflect that for that part of the graph.

Comment: Use custom axis-labels in that case. Might have to hand-engineer them in that case, check [the docs on that](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yticks.html). So basically you still use `y=y+57` for your line plot, and then invent custom `yticks=[0 50 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 0]` or something. You can then use a solid black line at `y=57` to 'simulate' your y-axis, though I don't think you can have x-tick marks on that then.

Comment: @Adriaan, you might be interested in the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 subplots. Here is an example:

```
data =  randi(50,20,20); % some data for the pcolor
y = mean(data); % some data for the top plot
subplot(5,1,2:5) % create a subplot on the lower 4/5 part for the figure
pcolor(data) % plot the data
colormap hot;
h = colorbar('east'); % place the colorbar on the right
h.Position(1) = 0.94; % 'push' the colorbar a little more to the right
ax = gca;
pax = ax.Position; % get the position for further thightning of the axes
ax.YTick(end) = []; % delete the highest y-axis tick so it won't interfere
                    % with the first tick of the top plot
subplot(5,1,1) % create a subplot on the upper 1/5 part for the figure
plot(1:20,y) % plot the top data
ylim([0 max(y)]) % compact the y-axis a little
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.Visible = 'off'; % delete the x-axis from the top plot
ax.Position(2) = pax(2)+pax(4); % remove the space between the subplots
```

Which creates this:

[image: onTop]

Comment: This seems like exactly what I needed! I had resigned myself to not having a solution so this is very useful. Could you comment your code a little before I 'accept' it?